# Alert that will check every specific day of the month

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I have multiple Grafana dashboards with alerts defined and the alert query is checked every, for example, 24h. This is not a problem and everything is working well.

I was wondering if there is any way to create an alert that will check every X day of the month. For example, every 12th of every month run the query and apply the alerting rules. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Many thanks,
Ricardo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time based alerts were requested almost 5 years ago, and finally 5 days ago a [pull request](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/33075) was created to add this future, its not yet merged but should be soon. Meanwhile you can use the workaround (credit to albertvaka) if you use Prometheus which is to use day_of_week() here is the [thread](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6592)